# How to configure loop & slidesPerView in SwiperV9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I used Swiper version 8.4.7, and found a [bug](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6435).
But since it is not supported, I tried to upgrade to version 9
But I, and not only ran into problems( [1](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6440) , [2](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6424) , [3](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6397) , [4](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6395) , [5](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6372) , [and similar](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6419) ) with `slidesPerView` and `loop` when trying to make a responsive slider using `breakpoints`

Since the 'loop' of the new version of the slider has a limitation (number of slides must be >= slidesPerView * 2), I'm stumped on how to make a looped slider.

For example, I have 4 slides:.

- On the phone it shows 1.  (`slidesPerView * 2 <= 4`) Should work
- On the tablet 2.    (`slidesPerView *2 <= 4` ) Should work
- On the computer 3.  (`slidesPerView *2 > 4`) will break

The idea of duplicating slides comes to mind, but there will already be problems with pagination:

- increasing the number of dots
- switch to slide an set it's active when you click on the dot (slide to original slide, or duplicate) and more.

I would like to create an infinite slider that would work correctly on different breakpoints.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Best to re-read their details about breakpoints at SwiperJS.
Per their website tutorial: 
...Not all parameters can be changed in 'breakpoints'....such parameters like 'loop' and 'effect' won't work...etc etc. 
Read:   https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters  
Other things like 'cube' and 'fade' won't cross mix, nor 'thumbs gallery' with other certain effects. SwiperJS is a good image slider though! 
Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks to your reply.
In breakpoints, I want to change the number of slides only.
I tried duplicating slides and creating a custom pagination, but, as expected, ran into a problem (when I get to the penultimate slide, navigation via point does not work until the last cloned slide).

My configuration looks something like this
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-swiper-forked-j5j5ws?file=%2Fsrc%2FCarousel.jsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A33%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A56%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A47%7D%5D

thanks!